# Django Restful_Api post Json for more than one record in a time

Tags: python, json, django

I use Django Restful Api ,I want to post records(more than one record!) in a time ,Models ,serialize,viewset are as follows

Does anyone has some advice? thanks advcance!

model

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    Company_Group = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
    Brand_Group = models.CharField(u'Brand Group',max_length=255, default="")
    Pref_Brand_Name_Flg = models.CharField(u'Preferred Brand Name Flag',max_length=255, default="")
    Pref_Brand_Name = models.CharField(u'Preferred Brand Name',max_length=255, default="")
    PrimaryContact = models.ForeignKey(UserRole, null=True, blank=True) #primarybroker
    Protect_period = models.CharField(u'Protect period',max_length=255, default="")
    # Pref_Brand_Name = models.CharField(u'Preferred Brand Name',max_length=255, default="")
    Brand_Name = models.CharField(u'Brand Name',max_length=255, default="")
    Brand_Name_SC = models.CharField(u'Brand Name in Local Language',max_length=255, default="")
    Year_Enter_Market = models.CharField(u'Entered Market in (Year)',max_length=255, default="")
    Category_Display = models.CharField(u'Category Display',max_length=255, default="")
    Category_1_Code = models.CharField(u'Category',max_length=255, default="")
    Category_2_Code = models.CharField(u'Sub Category',max_length=255, default="")
    Price_Low = models.CharField(u'Price Range - Low',max_length=255, default="")
    Price_High = models.CharField(u'Price Range - High',max_length=255, default="")
    Size_Low = models.CharField(u'Typical Store Size - Low',max_length=255, default="")
    Size_High = models.CharField(u'Typical Store Size - High',max_length=255, default="")
    Headerquater = models.CharField(u'Headerquater',max_length=255, default="")
    Status = models.CharField(u'Status',max_length=255, default="")
    Created_On = models.DateField(u'Created On',auto_now_add=True)
    Created_By = models.CharField(u'Created By',max_length=255, default="")
    Modified_On = models.DateField(u'Modified On', auto_now=True)
    Modified_By = models.CharField(u'Modified By',max_length=255, default="")
    Agreement_InPlace_Flg = models.CharField(u'TR Agreement in place?',max_length=20, default="")
    Web_Site = models.CharField(u'Web Site',max_length=20, default="")
    Comment = models.CharField(u'Comment',max_length=20, default="")
```

viewset

```
class BrandViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Brand.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BrandSerializer
```

Serializer

```
class BrandSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    PrimaryContact_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='PrimaryContact.id', read_only=True)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        many = kwargs.pop('many', True)
        super(BrandSerializer, self).__init__(many=many, *args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = data_export_setting.Brand_form_stand # +options ??
        #Brand_detail = serializers
```

"myTest code" :a.py

```
item = [{"id":"2","PrimaryContact_id":"00000","Pref_Brand_Name_Flg":"00000","Protect_period":"test_for_Protect_period_1","Pref_Brand_Name":"Test","Brand_Name":"Chanel Group","Brand_Name_SC":"test","Year_Enter_Market":"test","Category_Display":"test","Category_1_Code":"api","Category_2_Code":"api","Price_Low":"test","Price_High":"test","Size_High":"test","Headerquater":"test","Status":"test","Created_On":"2017-06-14","Modified_By":"2017-07-08","Modified_On":"000"},{"id":"3","PrimaryContact_id":"1111","Pref_Brand_Name_Flg":"11111","Protect_period":"ppppp","Pref_Brand_Name":"Test","Brand_Name":"Chanel Group 2","Brand_Name_SC":"test","Year_Enter_Market":"test","Category_Display":"test","Category_1_Code":"api","Category_2_Code":"api","Price_Low":"test","Price_High":"test","Size_High":"test","Headerquater":"test","Status":"test","Created_On":"2017-06-14","Modified_By":"2017-07-08","Modified_On":"000"}]

data=json.dumps(item)                                                     
def test_get_user_list_3():
    resp = requests.post(urlname,auth=AUTH,data=data,headers={ "Content-Type":"application/json","Accept": "application/json"})    
test_get_user_list_3()
```

if item as for one record ,it works

```
item ={"id":"1","PrimaryContact_id":"00000","Pref_Brand_Name_Flg":"00000","Protect_period":"test_for_Protect_period_1","Pref_Brand_Name":"Test","Brand_Name":"Chanel Group","Brand_Name_SC":"test","Year_Enter_Market":"test","Category_Display":"test","Category_1_Code":"api","Category_2_Code":"api","Price_Low":"test","Price_High":"test","Size_High":"test",Headerquater":"test","Status":"test","Created_On":"2017-06-14","Modified_By":"2017-07-08","Modified_On":"000"},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've spent a considerable amount of time trying to get this work. Below is the code that i've used to get this to do bulk creates.

The `get_serializer` method that's used by default for `ModelViewSet` passes in the data without `many=True` so you have to override it and make sure you check the request for a list instead of a dictionary.

That's the only change required to be able to bulk create items from a list.

models.py

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    # ------------------------------------------
    # Relations
    # ------------------------------------------
    Company_Group = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
    PrimaryContact = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)

    # ------------------------------------------
    # Attributes
    # ------------------------------------------

    # Brand attrs
    Brand_Name = models.CharField(u'Brand Name',max_length=255, blank=True)
    Brand_Group = models.CharField(u'Brand Group',max_length=255, blank=True)
    Pref_Brand_Name = models.CharField(u'Preferred Brand Name',max_length=255, blank=True)
    Brand_Name_SC = models.CharField(u'Brand Name in Local Language',max_length=255, blank=True)
    Pref_Brand_Name_Flg = models.CharField(u'Preferred Brand Name Flag',max_length=255, blank=True)

    # Record management attrs
    Modified_On = models.DateField(u'Modified On', auto_now=True)
    Created_On = models.DateField(u'Created On', auto_now_add=True)
    Created_By = models.CharField(u'Created By', max_length=255, blank=True)
    Modified_By = models.CharField(u'Modified By', max_length=255, blank=True)

    # Category attrs
    Category_1_Code = models.CharField(u'Category', max_length=255, blank=True)
    Category_2_Code = models.CharField(u'Sub Category', max_length=255, blank=True)
    Category_Display = models.CharField(u'Category Display',max_length=255, blank=True)

    # Pricing attrs
    Price_Low = models.CharField(u'Price Range - Low', max_length=255, blank=True)
    Price_High = models.CharField(u'Price Range - High', max_length=255, blank=True)

    # Store attrs
    Size_Low = models.CharField(u'Typical Store Size - Low', max_length=255, blank=True)
    Size_High = models.CharField(u'Typical Store Size - High', max_length=255, blank=True)

    # Company attrs
    Status = models.CharField(u'Status', max_length=255, blank=True)
    Comment = models.CharField(u'Comment', max_length=20, blank=True)
    Web_Site = models.CharField(u'Web Site', max_length=20, blank=True)
    Headerquater = models.CharField(u'Headerquater', max_length=255, blank=True)
    Protect_period = models.CharField(u'Protect period', max_length=255, blank=True)
    Year_Enter_Market = models.CharField(u'Entered Market in (Year)', max_length=255, blank=True)
    Agreement_InPlace_Flg = models.CharField(u'TR Agreement in place?', max_length=20, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Brand_Name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'brand'
```

serializers.py

```
class BrandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class BrandViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Brand
    serializer_class = BrandSerializer
    queryset = Brand.objects.all()

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'data' in kwargs:
            data = kwargs['data']

            if isinstance(data, list):
                kwargs['many'] = True

        return super().get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from .views import BrandViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'brand', BrandViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

I sent the data(JSON) using postman in this format:

```
[  
   {  
      "Brand_Name":"",
      "Brand_Group":"",
      "Pref_Brand_Name":"",
      "Brand_Name_SC":"",
      "Pref_Brand_Name_Flg":"",
      "Created_By":"",
      "Modified_By":"",
      "Category_1_Code":"",
      "Category_2_Code":"",
      "Category_Display":"",
      "Price_Low":"",
      "Price_High":"",
      "Size_Low":"",
      "Size_High":"",
      "Status":"",
      "Comment":"",
      "Web_Site":"",
      "Headerquater":"",
      "Protect_period":"",
      "Year_Enter_Market":"",
      "Agreement_InPlace_Flg":"",
      "PrimaryContact":null,
      "Company_Group":[  
         1
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Brand_Name":"",
      "Brand_Group":"",
      "Pref_Brand_Name":"",
      "Brand_Name_SC":"",
      "Pref_Brand_Name_Flg":"",
      "Created_By":"",
      "Modified_By":"",
      "Category_1_Code":"",
      "Category_2_Code":"",
      "Category_Display":"",
      "Price_Low":"",
      "Price_High":"",
      "Size_Low":"",
      "Size_High":"",
      "Status":"",
      "Comment":"",
      "Web_Site":"",
      "Headerquater":"",
      "Protect_period":"",
      "Year_Enter_Market":"",
      "Agreement_InPlace_Flg":"",
      "PrimaryContact":null,
      "Company_Group":[  
         1
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: I change some details ,  as follows:                                        
return super(BrandViewSet, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)                        
Thanks a lot ，it works !!! Thanks ~

Comment: @Deft-pawN On stackoverflow when a question is answered  you're supposed to up vote the answer and select it as the answer, this gives us recognition for our work in helping people solve problems.

Comment: I upvote a question ,then I see the message "Thanks for the feedback! So  I need to  earn a total of 15 reputation firstly ,Thanks for your help ~best wishes~

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [DRF documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior) you can utilize the `ListSerializer` to create multiple instances of the model.

Your best bet is to create a separate serializer(`ListSerializer`) with an your own custom `.create()` method for creating multiple instances of your model. Then in your view you write some business logic to check if it's a single object or a list of multiple objects and send them to the appropriate serializer for creation. Make sure you take a look at the `ListSerializer` and how to use `many=True`.

You can potentially use the same serializer with your own custom `.create()` method and have the business logic inside of there but look at the documentation and see the recommended way of creating multiple instances of objects.

Comment: In the BrandSerializer ,i have instantiating a serialize with many = true, Exactly,I think the problem exist the type of data in 
  "requests.post(urlname,auth=AUTH,data=data," 
 Just now I rewrite  'BrandSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer) ,
def create(self,validated_data): 
        print 'validated_data',validated_data
        return Brand.objects.create(**validated_data)'
the validated_data is empty ,it exists {}

Comment: @Deft-pawN I've added another answer that solves this with a minimal approach.